# Is it possible to have Scene in start()?

Tags: javafx

My teacher sent us a couple of questions and in one of the questions, he asked which is correct but arent both wrong? First I thought B) was incorrect because the start() has to be the same as show(). But then I realized that A) was using a Scene...is that even possible?

```
A)
    @Override
        
    public void start(Scene yourScene)
    
    {
        yourScene.show();
    }
    
B)
    @Override
    
    public void start(Stage primaryScene)
    
    {
        yourScene.show();
    }
```

Comment: You should read api documentation - it contains an answer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Comment: Neither of those will compile (assuming this is in a subclass of `Application`) as you have written them.

Comment: If you are looking at this and assuming one piece of code is correct, you would have to conclude that `A` is correct. `B` does not have a variable named `yourScene`.

Comment: @Sedrick Assuming this is a subclass of `Application` (which I assume is the intention), A will fail because of the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @James_D, I understand that, but coming from a teaching background and assuming the teacher did not make an error in the assignment, is how I based my opinion. I don't think the objective is compilable code. I think it is something more simple, like recognizing that one variable has not been declared.

Comment: what happened when you tried ;) coding is about writing .. code: that's one way to check your assumption (after reading the api doc). @Sedrick - we don't know what the teacher intended, do we? why should we exclude the conclusion the OP has reached :)

Comment: @kleopatra, I agree we don't know what the teacher intended. I think the first thing the OP needs to do is reach out to the teacher for clarity.

Comment: @Sedrick hmm I don't quite  agree: the OP reached a hypothesis (both are wrong) but is not certain whether or not s/he is correct - instead of reaching out (either to the teacher or the community here), I would suggest some research to collect facts to make certain (read the api doc, test both and interpret the errors, re-read the coursebook ..). Every teacher will be delighted with a well-argued case :)